# Why is Context needed to start activitites in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I understand what is context, and why it is needed, but why is it needed to start activities, why cannot it be done just by loading them Statically or by calling its constructor.

Comment: see the documentation for `Activity.getCallingActivity()` ...

Comment: _Return the name of the activity that invoked this activity.  This is
     * who the data in {@link #setResult setResult()} will be sent to.  You
     * can use this information to validate that the recipient is allowed to
     * receive the data._ This doesnt explain why i cannot create and launch an activity like this for example: `ActivityToLaunch.create()`, or `ActivityToLaunch activity = new ActivityToLaunch()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I cannot create and launch an activity like this:
>   `ActivityToLaunch activity = new ActivityToLaunch()`

Short answer: because you don't own an `Activity`.

That is, an `Activity` is a special component managed by the Android framework, but that allows you to add your application logic in predefined methods like `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc, etc, that are called later by the system.

...

Imagine that you want to lunch a third party app from your application, for example the default file manager to allow the user to pick a file from the SD Card. Obviously you will not be able to do something like this:

```
  FileManager manager = new FileManager()
```

because the FileManager classes (or any other third-party app's classes) are not accessible in your application code, so... hopefully you can see already a limitation with this approach.
That's why Android allows us to create an `Intent` where metadata about an `Activity` is given, pass it to `startActivity(...)`, and afterwards the system takes care of creating the started activity.

This was just one example, pretty sure there are other reasons why Android was designed like this.

Comment: Short answer makes it quite clear. Thanks for the explanation.